# Where yocto assign default kernel?

Tags: yocto

There are many kernel *.bb in

```
~/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux
```

I don't have **PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel** defined in local.conf

I also include meta-intel layer, I think meta-intel has it's kernel recipe also.

After built the yocto image, boot, and login, type 'uname -a' result is

```
Linux genericx86-64 5.4.20-yocto-standard xxxxx
```

I think yocto select it's poky kernel, but I can't find where this default setting located. ( which file setting this kernel )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can find it in the machine conf in :

meta-yourmeta/conf/machine/yourmachine.conf

The list of supported kernels by your machine is in recipes-kernel of your BSP.

Answer (score 0):

It's set by MACHINE, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @GreenTea I am not an expert on this, but the machine config files are setting the device trees. There are also karnel configuration files like the recipes in sources/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux, which are probably the base for all karnel config files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure of your setting of `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel` you can also use `bitbake -e <recipe>` to see how it is set.

Answer (score 0):

Poky itself has it defined with [default value](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#setting-a-weak-default-value)

```
poky/meta/conf/machine/include/qemu.inc:22:PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel ??= "linux-yocto"

poky/meta/conf/machine/include/x86-base.inc:20:PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel ??= "linux-yocto"
```